# Sometimes, Synaptics touchpad tends cursor to top-right corner

Tags: windows-7, drivers, asus-laptop, synaptics-touchpad

This has been a reoccurring issue for me, pretty much since I've owned this laptop (an ASUS G60JX.) Sometimes, the cursor will stop working properly and instead tend toward the top right of the screen. Basically, sometime into my usage (maybe after a couple hours) the touchpad will inevitably begin to malfunction, where it has confusing patterns of pushing the mouse cursor toward the top right of the screen. In addition, certain features (like momentum) seem to quit working entirely. It makes using the cursor extremely difficult.

I've been having this issue across very many drivers. Pretty much as soon as multitouch came into the mix, although I don't believe multitouch has anything to do with it. It appears that, in the state of malfunction, it doesn't matter how you touch the touchpad, but where you touch it. Certain regions do not seem to trigger the cursor to move to the top right corner. In fact, no specific region seems to, but some areas do so more often than others.

The issue can be resolved temporarily by putting the computer into sleep mode and awakening it. I have found no way to recreate this success without sleeping the computer or rebooting. Disabling and re-enabling the touchpad device does not do anything to resolve the problem.

This issue does not affect my WACOM tablet nor any USB mice, and can be resolved (not to my satisfactory) by uninstalling the touchpad drivers. I'm looking for a solution, or at least a workaround that doesn't require sleep mode.

Comment: Which version of drivers do you have installed?

Comment: Do you have a thumbstick in the middle of the keyboard as well?  I've had to disable that on laptops before for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @iglvzx I don't think it matters because I've had this problem with almost every version at least after 8.0, but it's v15.2.20 31Mar11. It's a new install of the generic drivers.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food I don't. I've tried disabling other things to no avail, but there's nothing like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some advice based on [this article](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001153.htm) :

**Disconnect other external input devices**

It may not be the touchpad that's causing your issue. If you have other input devices such as an external mouse, graphics tablet, keypad, etc., try disconnecting these devices to make sure they're not the cause of your issue.

**Disconnect from docking station**

If your laptop is only encountering this issue while connected to a docking station, it could be the cause of your issues.

**Make sure your laptop has the latest BIOS/chipset update**

Get updates from your manufacturer's website.

**Update touchpad drivers**

Make sure you have the latest drivers from your laptop manufacturer for your touchpad.

**Bad hardware**

If you've completed all the above steps and continue to have issues with your touchpad, it's possible you may have a physical hardware issue either with the touchpad or interface connected to the touchpad.

Comment: No external input devices are connected, no docking station, I updated BIOS before installing Windows last and it's still the latest, and my touchpad drivers are the last from Synaptics. It may be bad hardware, but the problem doesn't occur with the drivers not installed - I'm fairly sure there were older drivers that did not have the problem, but they were prior to multitouch, so I'd like to avoid that... (I might give in and try to find which version, but it can take a day to test just one version...) - Btw, if you have a potential workaround suggestion that's less obtrusive, i'm all ears.

Comment: In addition, I'd like to note that my problem occurs _while_ touching the touchpad in certain areas. Not while not touching it.

Comment: Are all your drivers up-to-date including chipset ? Other drivers to try : (1) The [generic Synaptics TouchPad driver](http://www.synaptics.com/resources/drivers) may work in cases in which model specific drivers don't. (2) Sometimes the Alps driver is weirdly enough reported as working better for Synaptics than Synaptics.

Comment: (1) The model specific drivers don't seem to work any better, so I've been using the generic since last Windows reinstall. (2) I will have to check that out, but I don't think Alps is multitouch compatible and I don't think it has pointer momentum, two features I'm using in Synaptic's generic drivers. Thanks for trying to help but I'm beginning to wonder if it really may be faulty hardware. Driver-wise everything should be latest as it was installed not but a couple weeks ago.

Comment: It may be bad hardware, as Synaptics touchpads do work for other people.

Comment: I'm just going to go with that. If I use a really old driver it no longer seems to have the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've got exactly the same problem, I would even describe it in an exactly same manner. Disabling and enabling it also doesn't work, on a completely different notebook (mine is HP Pavilion dv6-6b15ew).

What I've also found is going to the Control Panel and to the Mouse Setting and TouchPad tab there is a button called "reset devices" - clicking it solves the problem for me, but it's not very nice to have to do this every time this happens.

Comment: The "reset devices" tip may be helpful. I'm currently running without the drivers, but if this works at least I could tolerate it.

That being said it is disappointing that there seems to be no known solution to the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your touchpad first (cloth with a little rubbing alcohol make sure it's not too wet!), sometime dirt residue affects it when your touchpad is hot (normal heat generated from laptop). Does this happen in safemode as well? If not then it could be something with driver or other software. Lastly, if all fail you can try reformatting it.

Comment: Cleaning the touchpad doesn't help, but I can prove it's a software problem because sleeping the laptop does stop the problem temporarily, as mentioned. It's actually the nth time I've reformatted this laptop and had this problem, so I don't think that'll make a difference.

Comment: @JohnChadwick: Sleeping the laptop to fix the problem doesn't prove that it's a software problem.

Comment: @harrymc No but uninstalling the driver causes it to never happen, so it's a software problem...

Comment: @JohnChadwick: Likely you are right, but one can never be sure. Bad hardware + bad software = anything.