# Accidentally uninstalled my touchpad drivers from Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, drivers, mouse, touchpad

I had a problem with my cursor jumping to top-right of the screen and I found [an answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/377519/sometimes-synaptics-touchpad-tends-cursor-to-top-right-corner) to try to **disable** the touchpad driver, but I couldn't find the disable option and I **uninstalled** it instead.

It prompted me to delete the driver files which I did not, hoping I could revert back if it didn't work.

It also prompted me to reboot the machine to apply changes which I also have not, as of yet.

So the touchpad is still working, for now.

But now the driver is still uninstalled and it won't appear when I refresh or `Scan for hardware change`.

I'm afraid that now upon reboot I won't have my touchpad working at all, in which case I probably wouldn't be able to re-enable it again by going through all the settings.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your touchpad should work without drivers - almost all (if not all) touchpads emulate mice until a driver enables advanced features, and fall back to mouse emulation when driver shuts down (whether with your system or by uninstallation). So you can restart safely.

To reinstall drivers, head to your laptop manufacturer's website and look for drivers for your laptop model. Check what company manufactured your touchpad: it's probably Synaptics or ELAN. For ELAN touchpads manufacturer-provided drivers usually work best, for Synaptics you can visit their website and download latest drivers. Installation should be simple, just double-click the installer and follow instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see a problem. Just reboot the system and install the driver again, done.
It might be that your touch pad doesn't work, that is correct. But in Windows you can get (almost) anywhere with keyboard navigation.

Here are the steps you could take:

- Install a mouse before rebooting so you have something nice to navigate with in case the pad doesn't work.
- If you don't have a mouse, write down the steps to install the driver with just keyboard navigation.
- Reboot
- Reinstall the touch pad with the help of your mouse or the keyboard navigation.